# Change MacBook screen scaling via AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, automation, shortcuts-app

I am trying to change my MacBook Pro 14"s scale setting via AppleScript.
The setting should toggle two resolution settings.
I found the following script here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62664159/15705553

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    tell application "System Preferences"
        reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
    end tell
    
    set lowResolutionSettingIndex to 4
    set highResolutionSettingIndex to 5
    
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Built-in Retina Display"
        click radio button "Display" of tab group 1
        click radio button "Scaled" of tab group 1
        tell radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
            set isHighResolutionSet to get value of radio button highResolutionSettingIndex
        end tell
        if isHighResolutionSet then
            -- Toggle native resolution
            click radio button lowResolutionSettingIndex of radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
        else
            -- Toggle Default setting - "Retina optimized"
            click radio button highResolutionSettingIndex of radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
        end if
    end tell
    
    quit application "System Preferences"
    
    return input
end run
```

I changed "Built-in Retina display" to "Built-in Liquid Retina XDR Display" as shown in my System Preferences, but two errors occur:

- If I execute this script through Automator, I get the following error:

```
Syntax Error: System Events got an error: Can’t get window "Built-in Liquid Retina XDR Display" of process "System Preferences".
```

- If I execute it through shortcuts.app, I get the following error, even though I granted access to accessibility features for Shortcuts in System Preferences

```
System Events got an error: Shortcuts is not allowed assistive access.
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I've had success changing a Mac's Display Scaling with this script:

```
-- This script toggles a display's resolution between "Default for Display" and "Scaled" (at the largest scale factor.)

on run
    
    -- Make sure System Preferences is open, and view the "Displays" preferences pane
    tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
        repeat until window "Displays" exists
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
    end tell
    
    
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
        
        -- Bring up the "Display Settings" sheet, where the UI to change scaling is
        click button "Display Settings…" of window 1
        
        delay 0.2
        
        -- I'm only changing the scale of my 2nd monitor, which for me is the second display listed in the left-hand scroll area, so I need to click that 2nd row first.
        -- If you want to change the scale of your main display instead, just delete this tell block.
        tell outline 1 of scroll area 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
            set selected of row 2 to true
        end tell
        
        tell sheet 1 of window 1
            -- Is that display currently scaled?  If so, go back to the default resolution.  If not, then scale it.
            set theScaledRadioButton to radio button "Scaled" of radio group 1
            set isCurrentlyScaled to value of theScaledRadioButton as boolean
            if isCurrentlyScaled then
                click radio button "Default for Display" of radio group 1
            else
                click radio button "Scaled" of radio group 1
                -- If you want a different amount of scaling, change this button to "Resolution5" or "Resolution4", etc. down to "Resolution1"
                click button "Resolution5" of UI element 6
            end if
            
            -- Dismiss the "Display Settings" sheet, we're done using it.
            click button "Done"
        end tell
        
    end tell
    
    delay 0.1
    tell application "System Preferences"
        close window 1
    end tell
    
    -- Commented out, since I prefer to leave System Preferences open in the background so this script runs faster on the next run.
    --quit application "System Preferences"
    
end run
```

Note that you'll also need to go into System Preferences > Security > Accessibility, and check the checkbox to give Automator or whatever app permission to control your computer.